# MySQL - How to find records which date is between start date to end date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have two tables and trying to find records between start_date & end_date.

### campaign table

```
campaign_id     campaign_name       start_date              end_date
***********     *************       **********              ********
1               Deacon Navarro      2015-10-28 00:00:00     2015-10-31 00:00:00
2               Emily Oliver        2015-10-29 00:00:00     2015-11-04 00:00:00
```

### statistic table

```
id  campaign_id     comments    likes       created_date
**  ***********     ********    *****       ************
1   1               14          24          2015-10-28 00:00:00
2   1               34          12          2015-10-29 00:00:00
3   1               23          12          2015-10-30 00:00:00
4   1               23          24          2015-10-31 00:00:00
5   1               21          45          2015-11-01 00:00:00
6   2               12          17          2015-10-31 00:00:00
7   2               23          12          2015-11-01 00:00:00
```

Now I want to find all records from `statistic` table where `campaign_id=1` and `created_date` is between `created_date` to `end_date` from `campaign` table.

I need this output:

```
1   1               14          24          2015-10-28 00:00:00
2   1               34          12          2015-10-29 00:00:00
3   1               23          12          2015-10-30 00:00:00
4   1               23          24          2015-10-31 00:00:00
```

I have written very basic select query to find `start_date` & `end_date` from `campaign` table

```
SELECT start_date, end_date FROM campaign WHERE campaign_id = '1'
```

and I got this result:

```
start_date              end_date
**********              ********
2015-10-28 00:00:00     2015-10-31 00:00:00
```

but now I don't know how to find records from `statistic` table where `created_date` is between above `start_date` & `end_date`

Hope you are understand. I am not good with MySQL because I have just stared to learning so I need help If possible :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  SELECT statistic.* 
  FROM statistic, campaign
  WHERE
  campaign.campaign_id = '1'
  AND campaign.campaign_id = statistic.campaign_id
  AND statistic.created_date BETWEEN campaign.start_date AND campaign.end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
SELECT statistic.* 
FROM statistic
INNER JOIN campaign ON statistic.campaign_id= campaign.campaign_id;
WHERE statistic.created_date BETWEEN campaign.start_date AND campaign.end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM statistic AS s
INNER JOIN campaign AS c ON s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id;
WHERE c.campaign_id = 1
AND s.created_date BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date
```

For more information about JOIN syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).